# How to specify which extension method to call when ambigous call is found

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

So I have an extension method on `string` in assembly A.

Lets say it looks like this:

```
public static ToSomething(this string value, string somethingElse){...}
```

Now I have the exact same ToSomething method in assembly B which I am referencing as well.

I get the following error: `Ambigous invocation: A ToSomething, B ToSomething match`

Is there a way to specify which extension method you use since theyre both valid and both `allowed` to be referenced?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8474979/3583859 this might help you

Comment: No theyre both from different namespaces in different assemblies.

Comment: Yeah the static class call will do what I need